# How to set background color for a div when a html import vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js

Here is the html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
    <!-- import Vue before Element -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
    <!-- import vue-resource -->
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" :style="backgroudcolor"></div>
</body>
```

and I supposed to set background for the div whose id is 'app' ,and I've tried to bind a style object to its style, but it didn't at all..
here is the definition of the style object:

```
 backgroudcolor: {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
```

by the way, I put it in data.
Please help me, I'll be very grateful for that!

Answer (score 0):

Use the right css property name `background-color`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      backgroudcolor: {
        'background-color': 'red'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app":style="backgroudcolor">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: Your method didn't solve my problem...and there is my whole code:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" :style="backgroudcolor">
   
   </div>
</body>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
          backgroudcolor: {
                 'background-color': 'red'
               }
        }
    }
})
</script>
</html>`

Comment: @wangzewei you need to put something inside the `<div id="app"></div>` to see some results. With your code, the style is applied but not displayed if the div remains empty ([proof of concept](https://imgur.com/a/1djJfmI))